# commit-msg-linter.js: no such file or directory error

Tags: git, commit, linter

I am using Visual Studio Code for the frontend of the web application that I am coding and I never experienced any problems until I tried to make the first commit. This is the error message that I got:

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
cat: Desktop/frontend/v1-frontend/node_modules/git-commit-msg-linter/commit-msg-linter.js: No such file or directory
[stdin]:1
[423C:2D00][2024-01-11T12:37:02]i001: Burn v3.10.4.4718, Windows v10.0 (Build 19045: Service Pack 0), path: C:\WINDOWS\Temp\{20F2566E-E10E-446F-A7CA-0D851FFE2040}\.cr\VC_redist.x86.exe
 ^^^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:101:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:262:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:310:10)
    at internal/process/execution.js:77:19
    at [stdin]-wrapper:6:22
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:76:60)
    at internal/main/eval_stdin.js:29:5
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/process/execution.js:205:5)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
```

I checked if the file commit-msg-linter.js exists and it does. I tried deleting node_modules and running npm install again and I still get the same error. I tried changing the commit message that did not work either. I installed a higher version of git-commit-msg-linter and I got the same error again.

Comment: `Desktop/frontend/v1-frontend/node_modules/git-commit-msg-linter/commit-msg-linter.js` is a relative path and depends on your current working directory. It will only work if you are in the parent directory of `Desktop` (i.e. the user home directory)

Comment: I solved the problem by completely deleting the linter and husky packages.